# String jsx to jsx with curly braces

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I've read many articles and issues about this but it couldn't find anything to solve my problem
i have a jsx created from the backend and it's sent to the front end as a string, i want to parse it into regular jsx holding all the variables and functions
for example, i have a variable called data, which is an array of objects. and response is the string jsx generated from the backend

```
let data = [{}, {}, {}, ...]    

let response = '<div>
{data.map(obj=>(<div><span>{obj.prop1}</span> <span>{obj.prop2}</span></div>))}
</div>'
```

i tried dangerouslySetInnerHTML but it didn't work, it renders everything as a string. i also tried some npm packages but nothing worked for me very well.
is there anything i can do to make this work?

Comment: What packages have you tried?

Comment: There is no method in js to parse jsx, you can try npm pakages.https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-jsx-parser

Comment: I tried react-jsx-parser it can pass values form variables but not functions like map or conditionals